# Encriptar archivo App.config

Tags: c#

Tengo una solución con varias capas una capa de esas es la de acceso a datos donde tengo una clase con la cadena de conexión y en otra capa tengo varios métodos que construyen un xml

la conexión y unos datos que construyen el XML están en App.config por que son datos importantes como ip de servidores claves de acceso a unas APIS nombres de bases de datos y de tablas

Como puedo hacer la encriptación de todos estos datos para que no se puedan ver es decir que el App.config quede Encriptado o no muestre estos nombres

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <!--  KEYS DE CONFIGURACION XML-->
  <appSettings>
    <!--CLAVE DEL CLOUDFLEET -->
    <add key="KEY" value="Bearer ***" />
    <!--Valor de la base de datos para enviar a sap mediante el XML, Es decir es el nombre de la base de datos de SAP -->
    <add key="BaseDeDatos" value="***" />
    <!--Valor de la tabla para asignar al XML, Es decir es el nombre de la tabla donde llega la información -->
    <add key="Tabla" value="***" />
    <!--Valor de la llave primaria, Es decir es la llave primaria de la tabla -->
    <add key="LlavePrimaria" value="***"/>
    <!--Valor de la llave primaria-->
    <add key="ValorLlave" value="0"/>
    <!--Es el valor que tiene la acción del XML, Es decir es la accion que va hacer el xml "Insertar" -->
    <add key="Accion" value="Add"/>
    <!--Este es el nombre de la tabla del detalle, Es decir es larelacion d la tabla encabezado con la tabla detalle -->
    <add key="TablaDetalle" value="****"/>
    
   <!--CONSULTA DE SAP -->    
    <!--Valor de la base de datos para enviar a sap mediante el XML, Es decir es el nombre de la base de datos de SAP -->
    <add key="BaseDeDatos1" value="****" />
    <!--Valor de la tabla para asignar al XML, Es decir es el nombre de la consulta -->
    <add key="Tabla1" value="****" />
    <!--Es el valor que tiene la acción del XML, Es decir es la accion que va hacer el xml "LEER" -->
    <add key="Accion1" value="****"/>
    </appSettings>
  
  <!-- CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS -->
    <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Server=*****\****; Password=****;user=***;DataBase=*****" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <!-- SERVICIO DE SAP -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WSSincronizacion" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://****/WSSincronizacion/ServiceSincn.svc" binding="basicHttping" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_WSSincronizacion" contract="Sincronizacio.wwww" name="BasicHttpBindionizacion" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  
</configuration>
```

Comment: con encriptarlos y guardarloas asi te sirve, claramente despues los tenes que desencriptar donde los uses

Comment: Si, tienes documentación de como hacerlo

Comment: de sobra en la doc de microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace un tiempo tuve la misma problematica, investigue y encontre varias soluciones pero esta es la que entendi que era la mas facil de todas.

Resulta que el **webconfig** tiene digamos "una aplicacion" que se instala con **VisualStudio** que te permite encriptar este fichero. Pero esto no sucede con el **appconfig**, por tanto hay que "improvisar" un poco. La idea es cifrar el **appconfig**, con esta herramienta que encripta el **webconfig**, para ello vamos debemos renombrar nuestro **app.config** y ponerle como nombre **web.config**. Posteriormente abrimos la consola de windows y ponemos esto:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\salon\Desktop\Proyecto\Proyecto"
```

Esta parte :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef
```

Es donde se encuentra la herramienta que se instala con **VisualStudio** que es la que vamos a utilizar para encriptar nuestro **app.config**. La opcion **-pef** es la orden que se le da a esta aplicacion para que encripte el fichero.

Esta otra parte:

```
"connectionStrings" "C:\Users\salon\Desktop\Proyecto\Proyecto"
```

Se pone la seccion que vamos a encriptar del **app.config** y la ruta donde se encuentra el mismo. Aqui por ejemplo encriptamos la seccion **connectionstrings** del fichero **app.config**, que es donde estan las contraseñas.

Para desencriptar seria:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\salon\Desktop\Proyecto\Proyecto"
```

**-pdf** es la orden para desencriptar el **app.config**.

Cuando hayamos encriptado o desencriptado, volvemos a cambiar el nombre del **app.config**(recuerda que antes le habiamos puesto **web.config**), y le volvemos a poner su nombre original que es **app.config**.

**Importante:**

Para cifrar se emplea una llave propia de la pc tuya, por lo que si corres tu aplicacion en otra pc no ejecutara, por tanto tienes que cifrar cada aplicacion por cada pc que la uses, ya que la llave es propia de la pc.

Comment: ¡Uy! funciono muchas gracias.

Comment: Para empezar, no deberíais poner claves, tokens ni cosas así en ese archivo. Por mucho que lo cifres, el archivo se descifrará a la hora de arrancar la aplicación y en ese momento tendrás toda la información en memoria en texto plano. Un momento perfecto para que alguien copie las claves que le interese. Una aplicación de usuario no debería tener más tokens que los propios de la sesión (que además caducan en el tiempo). Para el resto de conexiones es preferible tener un backend que gestione todo eso

Comment: @eferion esa es la solucion que proponen los de visual studio y por algo sera

Comment: es que hacer esto es una barbaridad :) Es como si no quieres que te roben en casa y vas y pegas la llave con celo en el marco de la puerta. La información sensible siempre tiene que estar fuera del alcance de los usuarios. No debe estar de ninguna manera en su equipo