# ¿Cómo puedo evitar colocar directamente las credenciales de base de datos en la clase connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de C#, tengo la clase connection donde están las credenciales de la BD, me gustaría saber cómo evitar colocarlas directamente, ya que quiero subirlo a un repositorio público. Les comparto el ejemplo.

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class Connection
    {
        private static string getString()
        {
            return Settings.Default.HROBDConnectionString;
        }
        private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.10; Database=name;  User Id=admin; Password=database123;");
        

        public SqlConnection OpenConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }

        public SqlConnection CloseConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
            return connection;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Cargándolas desde un archivo properties.

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es, agregar la cadena de conexión encriptada, y en tu código accedes a tu cadena de conexión pero usar un método para desencriptarla.

Comment: entra aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421898/encriptar-archivo-app-config

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un appconfig en tu proyecto y agregar una conexión alli
[image: Como agregar un appconfig]

Luego en tu app config tendrias algo asi
[image: connectionstring appconfig]

En donde el nombre para llamar el connstring seria "DefaultConnection" (o el nombre que desees) y el valor que devuelve es lo que esta luego de "connectionString". Finalmente en el código lo llamarías de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Connection
{
    private static string getString()
    {
        return Settings.Default.HROBDConnectionString;
    }
    private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);


    public SqlConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    public SqlConnection CloseConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
        return connection;
    }

}
```

También si deseas puede hacerlo con un appsettings.json.
Espero haberte sido de ayuda. Saludos